# How to assign non-null property to button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, non-nullable

I am declaring an action for UIButton in myviewcontroller.h file like this

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender;
```

but I can see warning like `Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)`.
How can I resolve this issue?

thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this error? And you have added is IBAction and not declaration of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender
```

With

```
-(IBAction) loginClicked:(nonnull id)sender
```

Read more at: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25